# Implemention of casteld move in chess

Tags: java, oop, chess

I want to implement chess with Java as a exercise I'm trying to implement some basic parts like **pieces move** but I couldn't write this method in that way which if you want to change your piece location you have to know that is there another piece in way to go to new location (we know that just knight can't jump over other pieces).

And another problem is the implementation of castle move.

Relevant code:

**Piece:**

```
 enum Color {BLACK , WHITE}
 enum TYPE {ROOK , BISHOP , KNIGHT , QUEEN , KING , PAWN}

public abstract class Piece {

private boolean available;
private char x;
private int y;
Color color;
TYPE type;

public Piece(boolean available, char x, int y, Color color, TYPE type) {
    this.available = available;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.type = type;
}

public boolean validateMove(ChessBoard board,char fromX, int fromY, char toX, int toY) {
    if(toX == fromX && toY == fromY)
        return false;

    if(getX() != fromX || toY != fromY)
        return false;

    if(toX - 'a' < 0 || toX - 'a' > 7 || toY < 0 || toY > 7 || fromX - 'a' < 0 || fromX - 'a' > 7 || fromY < 0 || fromY > 7)
        return false;
    protectingTheWay(board);
    return true;
}
```

> (and all it's getter and setter).

**Bishop:**

```
public class Bishop extends Piece {


    public Bishop(boolean available, char x, int y, Color color, TYPE type) {
        super(available, x, y, color, type);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateMove(ChessBoard board,char fromX, int fromY, char toX, int toY) {
        if(super.validateMove(board,fromX, fromY, toX, toY) == false)
            return false;
        if( abs(toX - 'a' - (fromX - 'a')) == abs(toY - fromY) )
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Knight:**

```
public class Knight  extends Piece {
    public Knight(boolean available, char x, int y, Color color, TYPE type) {
        super(available, x, y, color, type);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateMove(ChessBoard board,char fromX, int fromY, char toX, int toY) {
        if( super.validateMove(board,fromX, fromY, toX, toY) == false)
            return false;
        if(toX - 'a' != fromX - 'a' - 1 || toX - 'a' != fromX - 'a' + 1 || toX - 'a' != fromX - 'a' + 2 || toX - 'a' != fromX - 'a' - 2)
            if(toY != fromY - 2 || toY != fromY + 2 || toY != fromY - 1 || toY != fromY + 1)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

and other pieces.

Comment: If you know what the castle move is, why are you having troubles implementing it? What specifically do you not know how to do?

Comment: Maybe dont start with on one of the most complex rules to begin with, why not implement moving the pawn first so that basically every pawn can move forward, then implement that it cannot move when a piece is standing in its way, maybe then implement that a pawn can move two steps in the beginning, then implement that he could take another piece in case it is left or right in front of him, then implement en-passant, then promote - why castle first? you can only castle if both rook and king did not move, if there is no field attacked between them and they have line of sight - pretty complicated.

Comment: `char x` is costing you dear, everywhere it's used, it's `- 'a'`. Also why do you have both `TYPE` and subclasses.

Comment: Another hint, I've heard that an efficient chess implementation often relies on noting that there are 64 spaces on a board and 64 bits in a `long`

Comment: @weston, costing "dear"? How expensive do you guess `int` subtraction is, let alone after runtime optimization? I agree that it's not a good idea, but not because of "cost", rather because it makes for weird, tangled logic.

Comment: @weston, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." - Dr. Donald Knuth.

Comment: @LewBloch costing dear in readability. Just because you want the user to see a letter, doesn't make that a good choice for the underlying datatype.

Comment: I disagree HEAVILY with you @weston. OP is not trying to write the most efficient way of a chess game, using a long and bit magic to move pieces is not at all a good idea for him. He is struggling with basic concepts, no need for very premature optimization. Regarding the char: I doubt there is any performance cost: the only thing OP might change is subtracting 'a' from both sides of a comparison and subtracting it from one side and comparing it to 7 or 0 - just compare against 'a' and 'h' in the first place.

Comment: @weston even from a programmers perspective I think it might very well be a nice idea to use a char for the data, it will make debugging potentially simpler if you are used to the chess notation.

Comment: @luk2302 I would rather `+ 'a'` in one place, the `toString` perhaps, great for debugging, than `- 'a'` in hundreds of places. Ever heard of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) anybody?

Comment: That it's readability isn't obvious from your first phrasing, @weston. Yet you then recommended a fairly subtle and difficult to code bitmask approach that would be even harder to read if done wrong. If bit `17` were set, how would one know what piece occupies the corresponding square? Which bits represent adjacent squares​, and in which direction? How tell the diagonal for a bishop capture across five squares? Let's get the OP to a good structure and game logic before "optimizing" with a difficult bit manipulation, which really isn't necessarily "efficient" anyway.

Comment: @weston The references to `a` can be dropped in most places it is currently referenced in OP's code and in the end there is no real difference between comparing to `0` or to `'a'` for checking out of bounds.

Comment: OP, you can ignore my 64 bit, it was just an interesting aside. An eye opener when I heard about it. If it peaked your interest, I'm sure there's some good material on Internet about it.

Comment: @weston@luk2302  could you please help to to implement the pieces move the can't jump over other pieces and how to implement the code that cant tell the computer that this spot is protected by black(or white).

Comment: @LewBloch re the 64 bit questions, my understanding would be that each piece has a long with a single bit set, and that's where it is. Two board level longs would reflect the locations of all white and black pieces, these can be constructed by bitwise `|` oring the individual locations. To see if a square is free is a simple bitwise `&` operation. Move patterns can also be expressed as bit masks, that you move through shifts to the pieces location. It's not readable at first glance perhaps, I agree, but it is very effective.

Comment: @LewBloch You can think of the longs as sets. And the operations as set operations. `long movesThatTakeAPiece = validMoves & whitePositions;`

Comment: Pretty complicated stuff, wouldn't you agree, especially when you just drop "Use a `long`" as the advice without any details?

Comment: @LewBloch No, I don't agree. And don't quote me as saying "Use a long" cause I didn't say that. Go back and read what I wrote.

Comment: OP, here's a wiki article about what I'm talking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard Just to prove I didn't make it up and this is what people do!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a cool exercise, and to me, it sounds like you're stuck in what is actually a design question, not a coding question. Even if you're not an OOP guru who's familiar with design patterns and SOLID, or even how many bits are in a Long, you can usually make your object oriented applications better by writing some text that describes the system you're building, and then taking note of the various nouns and verbs in that text.

So let's start with an example of a simple (obviously not comprehensive) description of your problem domain:

> Chess is a game, played on a board called a chessboard, with the goal
>   of capturing a specific piece on the opposing player's side - their
>   king. There are two players, one playing white and the other playing
>   black. Each player starts with a fixed number of pieces of various
>   types (king is among those). Each piece can only move in predefined
>   ways. The game starts when the white player makes a legal move, and
>   each player takes turns moving one piece at a time until the game
>   ends. The game can end when one in put in check-mate (meaning their
>   own king will be captured on the next move by their opponent and the
>   king cannot escape, block, or eliminate the threat of capture), when
>   there is a draw (where neither player can possibly capture the
>   opponent's king), or when one player surrenders to the other (because
>   ... reasons).

If you look over that description, take note of the various nouns and verbs. The nouns are candidate objects in your program, and the verbs are candidate operations (methods).

In the code above, I see objects representing some of the pieces and the chessboard. Compare what you have to my simple description above and ask yourself what other possible objects are missing. One interesting implication might be whether you consider a chess move to be an potential object or an operation that other objects can perform.

Specific to your question - how would you define castle in terms of the other objects and methods in your proposed system? Castling is certainly a specific type of move, and there are restrictions upon which pieces can participate in it, where it starts and ends, and which direction you may perform it (castling left != castling right).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, the Knight object's validateMove is working incorrectly? Let me know if I misunderstood.

Ok, first things first, in validateMove in Piece object, I'm not sure what this piece of code does:

```
if(getX() != fromX || toY != fromY)
    return false;
```

I don't see where getX() method is implemented, so maybe there's the problem.

Also, I know this isn't Code Review, but IMO you should keep coordinates as numbers and parse them to characters only when you need to show them on board or print them to user or whatever.

Another thing I have to say is that you're overcomplicating things in Knight's validateMove(). For example, we know that the knight's move is valid if it moves 2 spaces in one direction and 1 in the other, right? So what we can do is only check for that, and since your super method checks for coordinates out of board, there should be no other problems. For example, you can do it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean validateMove(ChessBoard board,char fromX, int fromY, char toX, int toY) {
    if (!super.validateMove(board,fromX, fromY, toX, toY))
        return false;

    int xIndex = Math.abs(toX - fromX);
    int yIndex = Math.abs(toY - fromY);

    if (!(xIndex == 2 && yIndex == 1 || xIndex == 1 && yIndex == 2)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you. :)